# Approximation of $f(x)$ at large values of $x$?

Tags: approximation

Suppose you a function $f(x)=1/x+x^2$.  At large values of $x$, it is closely approximated by $f(x)=x^2$.

Can Mathematica do this for me for a more complicated function?  How would I input the command?

Answer (score 8):

Take a series around infinity, dropping all $1/x^n$ terms.

```
Series[1/x + x^2, {x, \[Infinity], 0}]
(* x^2+O[1/x]^1 *)
```

Use `Normal` to obtain an ordinary expression from the `SeriesData` object.

A slightly more complicated example: the hyperbola represented by $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ has asymptote $y=x$ for positive $x$; so we get:

```
Normal@Series[Sqrt[x^2 - 1], {x, \[Infinity], 0}]
(* x *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the function as it is without converting to series than you may try this:

```
1/x + x^2 /. (y_ /; (Limit[y, x -> \[Infinity]] == 0) :> 0)
(*x^2*)
Sin[x] + 1/x /. (y_ /; (Limit[y, x -> \[Infinity]] == 0) :> 0)
(*Sin[x]*)
```

You may also find this link useful ([here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/AsymptoticBehaviorOfAFunction.html))

Comment: Note that this fails in cases like `Sqrt[x^2-1]` or `x^2/(1+x^2)`, resulting in no simplification, and zero, respectively, i.e. It only handles cases where the decaying terms are totally separated already.